# SUMIF a cell on the same row, in a certain column, contains a specific text

Tags: excel

I'm trying to sum all transactions on a spreadsheet of my bank statement. Let's say I have the following under columns B-F:

```
         B        C             D            E          F         G
        Date    Type       Transaction      Value     Balance    ???
row 4 23/05/14  BAC      Bank transfer A   1103.55    637.03
row 5 23/05/14  POS      Pizza purchase    10.00      627.03
row 6 23/05/14  POS      Coffee purchase   10.00      627.03
```

I'd like to make a new cell on column G which sums all values in column E that are on rows containing "POS" in column C. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and I believe the simplest way is by using `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF(C:C, "POS", E:E)
```

In other words, sum E:E if C:C equals "POS".

Comment: Thanks. I thought I'd tried this first time but it didn't work. May have been the fact I wasn't doing Ctrl + Shift + Return. Is there a way to amend it so that the text between quotations is only part of the full cell value?

i.e.
    =SUMIF(C:C, "GOOGLE", E:E)

Where the cell could actually say "434375 16May14, GOOGLE *APPANAME"

Comment: +1, this is not an array formula so just use in the "normal" way.

Comment: @MattKneale No need to Ctrl+Shift+Enter here, it's a normal formula. To allow for the 'part' condition, just use the star wildcard like this: `=SUMIF(C:C, "*GOOGLE*", E:E)` (so add if C:C has 'anything' + GOOGLE + 'anything')

Comment: @Jerry Wizards, all of you. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MattKneale You forgot the stars/asterisks :) [An example on GoogleSpreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vCa_bWrYf8DzU6iEu7XV5_UPaXrEoHn4BTsd0veoKZY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(IF(C4:C6="POS",1,0)*E4:E6)` is one way. Expand the ranges to taste.

Note this is an **array formula**: you need to press Ctrl + Shift + Return once you're done editing.